# Problem trying to implement segmentation technique on convolution with RGB filter

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, image-segmentation

I'm doing a research on segmentation of an image of an orange tree[Image 5].

I'm trying to replicate and experiment I found on Malik, Zeeshan & Ziauddin, Sheikh & Ahmad, Reyyan & Safi, Asad. (2016). Detection and Counting of On-Tree Citrus Fruit for Crop Yield Estimation. International Journal of Advanced Computer Science and Applications. 7. 10.14569/IJACSA.2016.070569. [Images 1 and 2]

The technique I want to use is image convolution with a filter mask (described on the article I mentioned and in the article below, on letter B).

The MALIK(2016) paper, uses a technique present on the paper A. B. Payne, K. B. Walsh, P. Subedi, and D. Jarvis, “Estimation of mango crop yield using image analysis–segmentation method,”Computers and Electronics in Agriculture, vol. 91, pp. 57–64, 2013.[Images 3 and 4]

I also tried to appply the NDI effect, but got a error with my code. What can I do to get the result I found on the two papers?

I'm working with python 3, OpenCV and Jupyter Notebooks. First I tried calculating the NDI:

```
NDI =  np.ones(np.shape(fruta), dtype= 'float64')
for i in range (len(fruta)):
    for j in range (len(fruta[i])):
        if (fruta[i,j,1] + fruta[i,j,2]) == 0:
            NDI[i,j,0] = 0
        else:
            NDI[i,j,0] = int( int(int(fruta[i,j,1]) - int(fruta[i,j,2]) ) / int(int(fruta[i,j,1]) + int(fruta[i,j,2]) ) )
```

I got this error:

```
C:\Users\pili_\Anaconda3\envs\python-cvcourse\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:4: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars after removing the cwd from sys.path.
```

It seems like an error with the image format or something.

I also tried using the effect (convolution with filter) I want to implement, but the result is not satisfatory, I dont know if I applied it right (I applied it without applying the NDI first, is that the problem?):

```
frutaNovo =  np.ones(np.shape(fruta), dtype= np.uint8)
frutaRGB = np.ones(np.shape(fruta), dtype = np.uint8)
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.float32)/9
frutaRGB = cv2.filter2D(frutaLab, -1, kernel)
for i in range(len(frutaLab)):
        for j in range(len(frutaLab[i])):
            soma = (int(frutaRGB[i,j,0]) + int(frutaRGB[i,j,1]) + int(frutaRGB[i,j,2]))
            if soma == 0:
                frutaNovo[i,j] = 0
            else: 
                frutaNovo[i,j] = soma/3
ret, frutaNovo = cv2.threshold(frutaNovo,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
displaygray(frutaNovo)
```

Malik paper: [Image 1]

[image: MALIK Paper]

Malik results: [Image 2]

[image: Malik results]

Payne paper: [image 3]

[image: Payne paper]

Payne results: [image 4]

[image: Payne results]

Original image: [image 5]

[image: Original Image]

My result: [image 6]

[image: My result]

Comment: I did not have time to look into the papers, but the error is easy to fix. The problem is that your addition in the condition can overflow, so the values have to be converted to int, as you do in the computation below: `if (int(fruta[i,j,1]) + int(fruta[i,j,2])) == 0:`

Comment: Althought,the result of NDI is also insatisfatory